# Modal do bootstrap 5 não abre

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Eu sou iniciante em programação, estou tentando executar esse código com o bootstrap mas não funciona simplesmente não abre o modal qual clico no botão, já tentei usar o cdn, npm e ate baixei os arquivos do bootstrap mas não vai.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap-5.1.1-dist/css/bootstrap.css">
  </head>
  <body>
      
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
      Abrir modal de demonstração
    </button>
    
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Título do modal</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            ...
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar mudanças</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript Libraries -->
    <script src="./bootstrap-5.1.1-dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Obs.: O código acima eu peguei da própria pagina de exemplo do bootstrap 5

Comment: Olha no console por possíveis erros.

Comment: O console nao retorna erro nenhum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No [Bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/), os atributos de controle `data-` da modal tiveram uma alteração, acrescentando-se `bs-`:

```
  Até a v.4    |    A partir da v.5
-----------------------------------------------------
data-toggle    -> data-bs-toggle  (botão para abrir)
data-target    -> data-bs-target  (botão para abrir)
data-dismiss   -> data-bs-dismiss (botão para fechar)
```

Exemplo:

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-6KY5s6UI5J7SVYuZB4S/CZMyPylqyyNZco376NM2Z8Sb8OxEdp02e1jkKk/wZxIEmjQ6DRCEBhni+gpr9c4tvA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-ewfXo9Gq53e1q1+WDTjaHAGZ8UvCWq0eXONhwDuIoaH8xz2r96uoAYaQCm1oQhnBfRXrvJztNXFsTloJfgbL5Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModal">
    Abrir modal de demonstração
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
     <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
         <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Título do modal</h4>
         <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
         ...
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar mudanças</button>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado ajudou muito <3

Comment: De nada! Não deixe de marcar a resposta como correta.